# Term in Hamiltonian when electric field is turned on

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electric-current, hamiltonian, quantum-hall-effect

In David Tong's [notes](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe.html) on Quantum Hall Effect, in his derivation of the Kubo formula, he says that turning on the electric field has the effect of adding a $- \mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{A}$ to the Hamiltonian, where $\mathbf{J}$ is the quantum operator associated to the electric current. He was working in the gauge $A_t = 0$ so that $\mathbf{E} = \partial_t \mathbf{A}$.
What I don't understand is how the term $- \mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{A}$ comes about.

Comment: This is the simplest term (i.e. lowest order in $A$) that is gauge-invariant. You can also derive it from the Peierls substitution.

Comment: @MengCheng Do you know where I can look up the derivation? The wikipedia page on Peierls substitution gives me nothing like this